# ggplot Vectors must be the same length

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector, dplyr, string-length

I am using "mutate" function in order to ignore the zeros from my vector called "temperature2".
I am plotting temperature vs fish abundance. Unfortunately, I have few temperatures which correspond to fish abundance=0.
therefore i sued the following approach:

```
`Num_plaice2<-finale$Num_Plaice[finale$Num_Plaice>0]`


`Temperature2<-finale$Temperature[finale$Num_Plaice>0]`

`finale %>%
  mutate(Temperature2=fct_reorder(Temperature2, Num_plaice2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Temperature2, y=Num_plaice2))+       ###Error: Column `Temperature2` must belength 92 (the number of rows) or one, not 82
  geom_point() `
```

I checked the lengths and they are the same but I get this error:
`Error: Column` Temperature2 `must be length 92 (the number of rows) or one, not 82`

Could you help me out?

Comment: I think the problem is with the `mutate`. `finale` has 92 rows, but `temperature2` has only 82 rows. There is probably a better way to do this. Perhaps set zero values to NA and then use `na.rm = TRUE` in `fct_reorder`. Difficult to be more specific without some data. You can include the data with `dput(finale)`

Comment: Hey @RichardTelford, thanks for your answer.

That's how it looks, but I counted my df and both  Num_plaice2 and temperature have 82 rows. 

How do I add my data on stack overflow?